# Submitting form issues: TypeError: this.form is null

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, forms, typeerror

I have a php page that displays all of the service logs for a given site in a table.

At the end of the table I have a new row that has an "Add new service log" button.

Clicking the button hides that row and displays a new row with a form and the desired inputs as well as a new row with buttons "Save" and "Cancel".

The "Save" button calls a Javascript function that checks that the key input has been filled out. When hitting "Save", I see in the console log

> TypeError: this.form is null

Here is my code:

```
 // SQL Query
 // Table data of queried results

 // Add a new service log   
 echo "<tr id='AddNew'>
       <td><input type=button value='Add New' onclick=\"$('#AddNew').hide();$('#AddNewHid').show();$('#SaveCancel').show();\"></td>
       <td colspan=12> &nbsp </td></tr>
       <form name='AddNewLog' method='POST' action='servicelook.php' id='AddNewService'>  
       <tr style='display: none;' id='AddNewHid'>
       <td><input type='text' value='$lastID' name='ticketid' size=10></td>
       <td><input type='text' value='$siteID' name='SiteID' size=4></td>
       <td><input type='text' value='$siteName' name='SiteName' size=20></td>
       <td><input type='text' value='$userid' name='takenBy' size=4></td>
       <td><input type='text' value='$now' name='callTime' size=20></td>
       <td><input type='text' value='' name='caller' size=20></td>
       <td><input type='text' value='' name='callPhone' size=14></td>
       <td><textarea name='issue' value = '' rows=3 cols=10></textarea></td>
       <td><textarea name='fix' value = '' rows=3 cols=10></textarea></td>
       <td><input type='text' value='$userid' name='solvedBy' size=4></td>
       <td><input type='text' value='$now' name='solvedTime' size=20></td>
       <td style='min-width:100px;max-width:100px;'><input type='checkbox' name='fup' value='fup'>Follow Up</td></tr>
       <input type='hidden' value='Yes' name='AddNew'>
       <input type='hidden' value='$userid' name='userid'>
       <input type='hidden' value='$session' name='session'>
       <input type='hidden' value='$siteid' name='siteid'>
       <tr  style='display: none;' id='SaveCancel'>
       <td colspan=2>
       <input name='save' type='button' onclick='inputCheck(this.form.issue);' value='Save'> &nbsp 
       <input type='button' value='Cancel' onclick=\"$('#AddNew').show();$('#AddNewHid').hide();$('#SaveCancel').hide();\"></td>
       <td colspan=11> &nbsp </td>
       </tr></form>";
 echo "</table>";
```

My inputCheck function looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function inputCheck(areaName) 
{
console.log("checking...");
if (areaName.value.length > 0)
{
    $('form#AddNewService').submit();
} 
else
{
    alert("You didn't describe the problem!");
}
} // end noteCheck function
</script>
```

I tried changing the submit button to this:

```
<input type=submit value=Save>
```

but nothing happens, nothing on the page or in the log.

Anyone have any idea as to what I am doing wrong or what the problem is here?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

After using Steven's advice, I was able to successfully submit the form.
However, the inputs aren't properly being sent. I am submitting to the same page so that the table reloads and and the user can see their latest entry. At the beginning of the script I have this:

```
if($AddNew == 'Yes')
 {
     echo "YES...Adding New";
     echo $ticketid .$SiteID. $SiteName. $takenBy. $callTime. $caller. $callPhone. $issue. $fix. $solvedBy. $solvedTime;

             // Start SQL Query
      }
```

The inputs return null. Is there something wrong with the way I am setting my inputs?

Comment: `<textarea>` elements should not have a `value` attribute. The value goes in between the opening and closing `textarea` tags.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I have changed this in my code.

Comment: While both answers were correct and did solve my problems, Steven's answer solved the original question's problem, but both Steven and RobG should get credit. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when this.form is null:

```
onclick='inputCheck(this.form.issue);'
```

replace with:

```
onclick='inputCheck();'
```

and edit your inputCheck method:

```
function inputCheck() {
    console.log("checking...");
    if ($('textarea[name=issue]').val().length > 0){
        $('form#AddNewService').submit();
    } else {
        alert("You didn't describe the problem!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I tried your suggestion, but the problem still persists.

Comment: `$('form#AddNewService')` is a good selectector (tag+id). Of course he need to have the form tag like that `<form id='AddNewService' ...>`

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the original *this.form.issue* reference, though it is significantly more efficient that using a jQuery selector.

Comment: Thanks for the new response. This fixed the problem. I am now able to successfully submit the form, but none of the inputs are being submitted. I have updated my question to explain.

Comment: This answer doesn't fix the problem, and in the context of the OP, "this.form" will never be `null`, though it might be undefined.

Answer (score 3):

The general strategy here is to make the save button a submit button, then put the validation on the form's submit handler and cancel submit if validation fails, e.g.

```
<form onsubmit="return inputCheck(this.issue);" ...>
```

then if validation fails, return `false` from the *inputCheck* function.

Your issue is probably because you have a form in a place it can't be, so it's being moved outside the table, i.e. you have:

```
<table>
  <form>
    ...
  </form>
</table>
```

which the browser is "correcting" to:

```
<table>
    ...
</table>
<form>
</form>
```

Now the form is outside the table but the controls are still inside it. So change the markup to:

```
<form>
  <table>
    ...
  </table>
</form>
```

so the table and form controls stay inside the form.

Comment: Thanks for putting that into perspective. I placed my starting form tag before the starting table tag, and that fixed my new problem of inputs not being saved. I should brush up on my fundamentals.

Comment: This made me realize I had a form within a form which was causing the same error. Thanks!